# JPA.getJPAConfig method not found on Play's API

Tags: playframework

I'm using the most recent version of Play (v.1.2.3) and my system need to read data from one database and persist it to another one.

I found on Play documentation there's a method called play.db.JPA.getJPAConfig() to do this job (I'll need to make native sql queries at the source database), but I'm not finding this method in the JPA class.

Am I using a wrong version or is this method placed at other class the documentation doesn't say?

Best regards,
Rex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When packing the 1.2.3 release some documentation from the 1.3 (master) branch leaked in. This documentation-error should be fixed now in the upcoming 1.2.4 release.

Comment: Thanks!
I was need a connection to the second database to make native queries (read only). Is there an option do get that connection? Or the only way would be the @PersistenceContext annotation on an entity/package-info.java?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to execute a native query, then you can simply use

`play.db.DB.execute()` or `play.db.DB.executeQuery()`

[Here is the API documenatation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/db/DB.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to answer this:

You can establish additional connection: decribe it in application.conf.

```
db_other.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
db_other.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_other.user=root
db_other.pass=
```

`Connection conn = DB.getDBConfig("other").getConnection()`

Look here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/model

**But:**

*Note: Play 1.2.3 does not support multiple databases. The Support for multiple databases section was included in this documentation page by mistake (the feature is only in the master branch on github).*

As already said @mbknor