# Multiple Databases in play framework

Tags: playframework, multiple-databases

I'm trying to establish a second database connection to another database on another server. We're using play framework 1.2.4 and I found the following documentation for 1.2.3.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/model#multiple

```
application.conf:
db_other.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
db_other.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_other.user=root
db_other.pass=

Connection conn = DB.getDBConfig("other").getConnection()
```

This didn't worked for me so I did a little more search and found the following article.
This article told me that the above configuration leaked in from the 1.3 master branch and will be available in the future...

[JPA.getJPAConfig method not found on Play's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001809/jpa-getjpaconfig-method-not-found-on-plays-api)

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/706

Can anyone give me a way to do some simple queries to that other database? I think I'm not the only one who wants to use multiple databases.

Thanks!

Comment: For queries to another db on the same server im using this List test = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM other_db..TABLE").getResultList(); in sybase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To occasionally read data from other database, you can also use plain old JDBC :

```
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        String url = "YourJdbcUrl";
        Class.forName("YourDriver").newInstance();
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "XXX", "XXX");
        pstmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Fill your data into Play Model instances here.
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (pstmt != null) pstmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (c != null) c.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    }

    render(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how I'm connecting to other databases now until there is another solution.

```
Connection c = null;
try {
    ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClass("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver");
    ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:server:4100/db");
    ds.setUser("user");
    ds.setPassword("pass");
    ds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(10);
    ds.setCheckoutTimeout(5000);
    ds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);
    ds.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    ds.setMinPoolSize(1);
    ds.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(0);
    ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(10);
    ds.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);

    DB.datasource = ds;
    try {
        c = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";

try {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\n");
    }

    c.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```